# ANTLR4 Print at the end of parsing

Tags: parsing, printing, antlr4

Is there a way to print @members in ANTLR4 at the end of parsing?

```
grammar test;
@members{
int count = 0;
} 

sentence :  (a..z|A..Z)* r;
r        :  [\r\n]+ {count++;};
```

Comment: Am I right that you want to print `count` at the end of parsing? Yes there is a way: `count++` is yet executed at the end of parsing `r` (and not as you probably expected at each iteration).

Comment: @StefanA, I changed the code a bit.
I will need to print the end count. If I just add {System.out.println(count);}; then it just prints 1 2 3 4 ...

Comment: I suggest you provide a compiling grammar (this one does not) and the test program.

Comment: @StefanA I'm fairly new with ANTLR, not quite sure how to go about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I get your question right, but as StephanA said, your grammar is not ANTLR4 compliance. I slightly modified your grammar to this:

```
grammar Test;

@members{
int count = 0;
} 

sentence :  WORD (r WORD)* {System.out.println(count);};
r        :  WS {count++;};

WORD : ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z')+;
WS :  [ \r\n]+;
```

This grammar will accept `This   is a     test` (with `count` = 3 at the end) but will reject `This is a test` or `This is a test` (`WS` at the end). I added a `root` rule which represents the parse tree root and I display the `count` at the end of this rule.

Is this what you want?

EDIT

I just refactored the grammar, the `root` rule is not really useful actually (my bad).